# Delaying Runtime.exec to give Apache POI time to write a file?

Tags: java, apache-poi, runtime.exec

I have written a method that successfully exports data from an array to an Excel file. However, I would like Java to automatically open the freshly created Excel file when Apache POI is done writing it.

My code looks like this:

```
public void exportData(Object[][] data, String[] columnNames) {
    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();

    // Export logic here...

    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(new File(myFilePath));
    wb.write(fileOut); // Write the Excel file
    fileOut.close(); // Close it
    openFile(); // Open it with Excel
}

public void openFile() { // Excel file opening method
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start " + new File(myFilePath));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It behaves as follows:

- When I call exportData() during runtime, the Excel file is written as it should be, **but is not automatically opened.**
- If I "manually" call openFile() again afterwards (through a JButton ActionEvent, for example), **it works.**
- If I start my application in NetBeans' debug mode and proceed step by step, **it works without needing to manually call openFile() afterwards.**

My guess is that something is being done in the background here, and that it takes some time, while my program goes on; therefore, I think my Runtime.exec() may happen *before the file is ready to be opened*.

Do you think it is the case? Is there a better way to do it? If not, how can I delay Runtime.exec() accordingly?

Comment: Maybe `.flush()` your output stream? Also, you should close in a finally block.

Comment: Join us in the 3rd millennium and use `ProcessBuilder` instead of `exec`.  As general advice: 1) Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces. 2) Change code of the form `catch (Exception e) { ..` to `catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); // very informative! ..`

Comment: Thank you. As for the stack trace, I merely removed that part of the code when pasting it here. There is no exception raised anyway.

Comment: Does `Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(myFilePath));` work better ?

Comment: @ARRG: Yes! Actually, I realized the problem still existed with `ProcessBuilder`. Yours always work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what is the exact problem that prevents your command from working. But in general, when you want to open a file, it makes sense to use `java.awt.Desktop` instead of spawning a process to do so.

So in your case

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start " + new File(myFilePath));
```

Becomes

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(myFilePath));
```

AWT takes care of ensuring everything goes smoothly, and you get better cross-platform support this way.